# Create WindEdt 10.0 shortcut

Tags: winedt, shortcut

I am trying to create a customized shortcut in `WinEdt`. After reading a few posts on tex.stackexchange I thing I am close to be able to do it, but somehow it is not working.

I am trying to define the combination of keys <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to generate the following lines: `{\ttfamily \ttfamily}`.

So what I did was the following:
`Options -> Options Interface`. In the interface that opens up in the lefthand column, double click `Menus and Toolbar`... and then double click `Main Menu`. That's when the `MainMenu.ini opens`.

Then I located the line:

```
  MENU="Shortcuts"
  CAPTION="Shortcuts"
  INVISIBLE=1
```

And right after that line I added:

```
ITEM="$\ttfamily"
CAPTION="&ttfamily"
MACRO="Ins('{\ttfamily \ttfamily}');"
SHORTCUT="32833::Alt+G"
```

Then I reloaded the script, but the shortcut is not working. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem in the line

```
SHORTCUT="32833::Alt+G"
```

In fact, the scan code (`32833`) belongs to the <kbd>Alt+A</kbd> combination..., and it prevails on <kbd>Alt+G</kbd>. Try to press <kbd>Alt+A</kbd> and you will see what happens.

The right scan code for <kbd>Alt+G</kbd> is `32839`.

If you want to insert the right scan code, simply double-click on `SHORTCUT` and insert the right combination.

Note, however, that <kbd>Alt+G</kbd> is already assigned to the `Greek` popup menu, so I suggest you to think of another shortcut, for example <kbd>Alt+A</kbd> which is not assigned.

If you want <kbd>Alt+G</kbd> and only that, you have to remove that shortcut from the other menu item.

To know which shortcuts are already used, go to Options Interface -> Menus and Toolbars -> Main Menu and in Tree toolbar choose Copy to Clipboard -> Shortcuts, then paste it in a blank data document.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the insightful answer. Where can I check scan codes for remaining shortcuts?

Comment: BTW: What's the purpose of inserting `{\ttfamily \ttfamily}`?

Comment: It is just a style defined wuth the "lstset" package to insert code within a document.

Comment: @volcompt Ah, OK.

Comment: @volcompt Added in the answer.

Comment: thanks for the update, but I was actually looking to understand where to find the scan codes, i.e. how to I know the scan code for something like "alt-ctrl-5" ?

Comment: @volcompt Scan codes are hardcoded. You can discovered the one corresponding to a shortcut by double-clicking on `SHORTCUT`, inserting a shortcut and then pressing OK. At this point, if you look at MainMenu.ini, you will see the corresponding scan code.